# Add divs to a dragscrollable list dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, draggable

I'm using HTML5, JS and JQuery to build a web page. Below I put this little piece of code, that represents a scrollable list (`devsScrollList`), which will be dragscrollable vertically when the size of itself overcomes the box's one (`devsBox`).

```
<div id="devsBox">
    <div id="devsScrollList"></div>  
</div>
```

In particular, in the `devsScrollList` div, asynchronously, I add some divs. In other words, the list will be filled slowly, and it is initially empty.
For this purpose I'm using the dragscrollable plugin. (http://hitconsultants.com/dragscroll_scrollsync/dragscrollable.js)

I add the divs to the `devsScrollList` as following:

```
$('#devsScrollList').append("<div id=" + tmpId + " class=\"dev devScrollListSelector\">" + tmpName + "</div>");
```

While to made the `devsScrollList` div dragscrollable I use the following line:

```
$("#devsBox").dragscrollable({dragSelector: '.devScrollListSelector', acceptPropagatedEvent: true});
```

Now, the problem is the following:

1. If call the `.dragscrollable()` before to add the child div (let me say at initialization time), the list doesn't scroll, because the selector do not find any match.
2. If call the `.dragscrollable()` every time I add a div, since the `.dragscrollable()` is applied on the external container (in this case devsBox div), the event 'mousedown' is registered many times in each child div the selector finds. Result: the list works (it is scrollable) but it is unmanageable, because many events are triggered, as many as there are elements in the list, at the time of the `.dragscrollable()` invocation.

So, how could I fix this issue?

Comment: Can you post all of your HTML and JS?

Comment: The files consist in one thousand of code lines. Maybe it's difficult to paste. What are you looking for in particular?